# Do Central Banks pay interest on reserves?

Tags: macroeconomics

In deposits, banks pay an interest to the lender. Similarly, do the CBs pay an interest on bank reserves?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Many do. I don't think they all do. Link: http://www.frbsf.org/education/publications/doctor-econ/2013/march/federal-reserve-interest-balances-reserves